# CSS duplicate rules best practice

Tags: html, css, sass, less

Suppose I have html like this, and I use LESS:

```
<div class="one">
  <p class="a"></p>
  <p class="b"></p>
</div>
<div class="two">
  <p class="a"></p>
  <p class="c"></p>
</div>
```

And I want to style paragraph class "a" with color red, "b" with color blue and "c" with color yellow. So I have the following:

```
.one, .two {
  .a { color: red; }
  .b { color: blue; }
  .c { color: yellow; }
}
```

And I know that it can also be written as:

```
.one {
  .a { color: red; }
  .b { color: blue; }
}

.two {
  .a { color: red; }
  .c { color: yellow; }
}
```

I know my examples are a bit lacking, but my question is, what's the difference between the two? The second example is a bit longer but doesn't define rules where it shouldn't belong.

So my question is what is the disadvantage of placing rules that have no meaning to save some lines (like what I did on the first example)? Will it generate more rules, make it slower, etc..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not simple:

```
.a { color: red; }
.b { color: blue; }
.c { color: yellow; }
```

The difference between those two is that first one covers all six types:

```
.one .a, .one .b, .one .c, .two .a, .two .b, .two .c
```

While the second one only covers 4:

```
.one .a, .one .b, .two .a, .two .c
```

With respect to your markup - no difference at all, except that the very first case (without `.one` and `.two`) will be sliiiiiightly faster.

Also, see [this](http://www.css-101.org/descendant-selector/go_fetch_yourself.php).

Comment: There needs to be about 40 more i's in slightly! Great answer, though. Don't be specific unless it's required.

Comment: I know classes "one" and "two" are unnecessary in this case, but let's just assume they are there for specificity. I know the second one covers less cases, and does not include the unnecessary ones. So my question is, which of them is better? The first one is shorter but will it generate unnecessary rules and be slower in any case? Also, the examples are just for explaining and I'm asking about the unnecessary rules generated not if the parent class is specified. Thanks.

Comment: In that case the first one makes more sense. Those are absolutely identical with respect to rendering speed, but first one is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

Unless for styles hierarchy reasons, it's simpler to just write:

```
  .a { color: red; }
  .b { color: blue; }
  .c { color: yellow; }
```